# Embedded Webview for Windows Phone 8?

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, webview

I know that embedded webview is only officially supported for android and ios. But has anyone tried to use embedded webview for windows phone 8. I want to start cordova-based view from a native list view. Don't know whether it's possible since my c# knowledge is also quite limited. I want to hear from expert before digging further in the code.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I create a sample project where a cordova webview could be started from a native view. Check it out here: https://github.com/peacemoon/cordova-wp8-embedded-webview